# Vb.net Convert Integer DBNULL to 0 - error

Tags: vb.net, integer, dbnull

I'm having this method:

```
Private Function convertInteger(intInteger As Object) As Integer

    If IsDBNull(intInteger) Then
        convertInteger = 0
    Else
        convertInteger = cInt(intInteger)
    End If

End Function
```

But it returns this error:

operator '=' is not defined for type 'integer' and type 'dbnull'

Im trying to convert a DBnull value to 0..

But the problem is that the value im trying to convert is not always DBnull.. so how should i handle this?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Nullable(Of Int32)`? It has a `HasValue`. property.

Comment: **Enable `Option Strict` in the project settings.** Then fix the compile errors. Then come back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Function convertInteger(intInteger As Object) As Integer

    If intInteger = DBNull.Value Then
        Return 0
    End If

    Return intInteger

End Function
```

As suggested by [Tim Schmelter], look into Nullable types

Comment: Please don't suggest the old VB syntax `methodName=returnValue`, that works only for compatibility reasons. VB.NET works the same as C#, it has a return value: `return 0`.

Comment: Am sorry for that. I didn't even see the function name

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Function convertInteger(ByVal intInteger As Object) as Integer
   If IsDBNull(intInteger) Then
       Return 0
   Else
       Return CInt(intInteger)
   End if
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Private Sub readValue()
    Dim cSql As String
    Dim oCnn as OleDbConnection
    Dim oCmd as OleDbCommand
    Dim oDataReader as OleDbDataReader
    Dim valor as Integer

    oCnn.open()

    cSql = "SELECT FIELD_NAME FROM TABLE"
    oCmd = New OleDbCommand(cSql, oCnn)
    oReader = oCmd.executeReader

    if oReader.HasRows then
       oReader.read()
       valor = IIf(IsDBNull(oDataReader("FIELD_NAME")), 0, oDataReader("FIELD_NAME"))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Edit post to add proper code formatting. Also consider adding any explanation to your code.